# Confused about when a compound noun needs an article or not

Tags: noms, mots-composés, nom-composé

I keep tripping up on this and it's super frustrating, just when I think I get it, I seemingly don't get it.

Some examples:

- Une tasse de sagesse
- Une tasse de vin
- Le blanc de la sagesse
- La tasse de vin

So these are all compound nouns as far as I'm aware, why does 1 need 'de la' and the rest all have just 'de' to make the compound?

So confused!

Answer (score 1):

- Une tasse de sagesse

Here, we are talking about "sagesse" as a resource, something that can be figuratively consumed. No articles are to be used when you are taking "an amount" of something.

- Une tasse de vin

Same reasoning. Something you can take an amount of → article.

- Le blanc de la sagesse

Here we are talking about "sagesse" as an idea, thus an article is needed.

- La tasse de vin

Same as for "une tasse".

Answer (score 1):

With *"X de la Y"*, X is contained in Y, so to speak. X is a property or a part of Y.

> le blanc de la sagesse
>
> la couleur de la voiture
>
> le bouchon de la bouteille

With *"X de Y"*, Y is contained in X.

> Une tasse de vin

It might not be the most rigorous explanation though.

Comment: hmmm, but "le blanc de la sagesse" is *general* - the white of wisdom (in general).  Whereas your examples are specific, e.g. the colour of THE car, the cork of THE bottle.

Comment: “Wisdom” is being referred to as a specific thing here, and it’s not an amount you can take stock of, like wine.

Answer (score 0):

When you use "la", it mean you talk about "this". 
When you dont use "la", you talk about "one of these".

Like :

This cup = La tasse.
One of these cup = Une tasse.

It's not literally the translation but it help to understand.

Comment: thanks but that's nothing to do with the question asked.